# MVC Model Binding Issue always NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add a new MVC ActionLink that when pressed goes to an action and gets bound to the input parameter but it doesn’t seem to be working

I Have this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("OPTIN","Optin", "Admin", new {id = Model.Publications[i].ID})
```

And then the Optin method on the Admin controller:

```
 public ActionResult OptIn(int? id)
        {
            if (id.HasValue)
            {
                var temp = id.Value;
            }
```

I want the id to get mapped to the input parameter but it is always NULL and Model.Publications[i].ID is always 5. What am I doing wrong? Do I have to make ID part of a model?

Comment: The ID on your Publication object is in int, correct? It's not set up as something that can't convert to int?

Comment: Fire up your HTML page, and give us an example URL that is generated from your ActionLink.

Comment: <a href="/Admin/Optin?Length=5" id="5">OPTIN</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you have your `ActionLink` method set up is wrong. I'm GUESSING the override you're using is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124(v=vs.118).aspx). However, you'll want to be using is [string, string, string, object, object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972(v=vs.118).aspx).

By the URL in the comment on your question, the ID that you're setting is the HTML attribute, not a part of the URL.

If you change your call to the following, it should give you what you need:

```
@Html.ActionLink("OPTIN","Optin", "Admin", new {id = Model.Publications[i].ID}, new { })
```